# Merge Failed when Merging Contact Record

Tags: merge

I am working with merge DML. I want to merge the Contact whose Account owner is same. Like, I have 4 record 2 of them Account owner is same and another 2 Contact's Account Owner is same. I have to merge those 2 Contact with same Owner. In this case after merging only 2 record will remain of different Account Owner. For that I have done below

```
if(setSameOwnerId.size() > 1){  

                    Map<Id, List<Contact>> mapIdContact = new Map<Id, List<Contact>>();

                    for(Contact con : contactList ){

                        if(setSameOwnerId.contains(con.Account.OwnerId)){

                            if(!mapIdContact.containsKey(con.Account.OwnerId)){
                                mapIdContact.put(con.Account.OwnerId, new List<Contact> {con});
                            }
                            else{
                                mapIdContact.get(con.Account.OwnerId).add(con);
                            } 
                        }  
                    }

                    for(Id accountownerId : mapIdContact.keySet()) {
                        Contact[] conListToMerge = mapIdContact.get(accountownerId); 

                        Contact mastercon = conListToMerge[0];

                        List<Contact> lstcon = new List<contact>();  

                        if(conListToMerge.size() > 1 ){
                            Integer i=2;
                            Boolean flag = false;

                            while(true){
                                List<Contact> tempList = new List<Contact>();
                                Integer j = (i+1);
                                for(;i<=j;i++){ 
                                    if(conListToMerge.size() >= 1){  
                                        tempList.add(conListToMerge[i-1]);  
                                    }else
                                        break;
                                }  
                                if(tempList.size()>0)  
                                system.debug('#### templist : -'+tempList + '#### mastercon : -' + mastercon.Id);
                                    merge mastercon tempList; 

                                if(i>conListToMerge.size()) 
                                    break; 
                            }  
                            //Update Status and Is Processed field.
                            dupList[0].zStatus__c = 'Merged Successfully';
                            dupList[0].zisProcessed__c = true;
                            update dupList[0];  
                        }  
                    }
```

I am getting the Debug Proper. Master Contact and Contacts to merge. But At Merging time I am getting an error below

> System.DmlException: Merge failed. First exception on row 0 with id
>   003230000028OtZAAU; first error: INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE,
>   Contact: bad field names on insert/update call: Account: [Account]

I couldn't understand meaning of Error, how to remove this Error Please Help me!

Comment: Your error is most probably coming from the line  `update dupList[0];`  Where is your dupList is populated? What fields does it contain? Please paste the relevant code.

Comment: A problem with your code: I think you forgot opening { and closing } after if(tempList.size()>0) Right now, the merge is executed unconditionally.